# How to backup a backup in Acronis True Image?

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

I have a backup in an external HDD, and I wanted to make a copy of it for security...which is the best way?
As far as I ca see, I can copy the backup folder to another HDD, or I can make another backup in Acronis with the same options of the original one, it it there another option? Like configuring Acronis automatically to make the same thing in another location?

Answer (score 1):

In Acronis True Image/Acronis Backup & Recovery, look for features such as [**Backup reserve copy**](http://kb.acronis.com/content/16241), [**Dual destination/Backup replication**](http://www.acronis.com/support/documentation/ABR11/#11399.html) etc.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Of course, you can always manually/using a script make a copy of the files. For safety you can verify by comparing hashes (MD5/SHA-1) of the copy and original backup files.