# Replicate Windows 7 Backups

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, replication

Like many users, I'm cautious about losing data. My primary drive uses the built-in backup utility in Windows 7 to backup onto a pair of larger mirrored drives. I want to a way to automatically copy/synchronize that backup onto an external disk daily. I rotate that external drive out every week or so to an offsite location.

Currently, I manually wipe the external drive and copy-and-paste the backup from the mirrored drives. It doesn't seem like I should have to do it manually, but rather should be simple to set up automatically. What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Ramhound, if you have a suggestion, please expand and add as an answer, that comment was not really helpful.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/548229/how-to-backup-a-backup-in-acronis-true-image) might be of use to you.

Comment: @JulianKnight - Due to the negative experience I had I almost never post an answer.  I don't even recall what I said that you claim was helpful ( although I disagree with that statement ).  I imagine I said something along the lines of using a program that duplicates the hdd's state automatically and allows the user to make continous backups instead of having to archive/delete previous backups.

Comment: Urrm, then what's the point? Actually, looking at your previous answers you seem to be getting pretty good results overall.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the more fully featured backup utilities for this. Such as [SyncbackSE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/products.html) or one of many others. A decent backup utility will allow detection of the appropriate drive when it is attached and allow running of a script that can remove the redundant backup before copying the new backup.

Personally, I no longer do things this way for my own computers. I accept the overhead of rebuilding a computer if it breaks since the likelyhood is that the OS and all of the applciations will have moved on and it is likely to be a good idea to rebuild from scratch anyway for the odd occasion these things happen. For data, I use [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) to make 2 backups. One to another PC on-site so that I can restore data quickly (this is free with CrashPlan). The other to the CrashPlan remote servers (this is charged of course though a family plan is very reasonable for up to 10 computers with unlimited storage. You can replace this by doing a space swap with some one off site, which is free). CrashPlan is fully encrypted and supports multiple version backups.

Comment: Why don't people leave a comment when they downvote? Are they embarrassed? SU is about sharing intelligence. Downvoting without an explanation prevents people from improving - come on! What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response. I've used Acronis TrueImage in the past, but dropped its use for one reason or another. I'll check out SyncbackSE.

Comment: A pleasure, feel free to upvote the answer if it is of use to you in order to offset the anonymous Mr Negative! ;)